# 403 Forbidden Error. MVC 5 Web Project with Cookie Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I'am getting some strange behaviour from my MVC Web Project.

I am using MVC 5 and .net4.6.1. Auth is with Cookie Authentication.

My Publish Options are PreCompile with Updatable Option set to True.

When I publish my WebApp I click publish, get the Folder Contents and copy them to my CloudServer (IIS 8.5).

Everything works find until some point (can not say exactly when (couple hours)) I am getting a 403 Error and need to republish my webapp.

Any Ideas what the problem might be?

Markus

**UPDATE 1**

```
   public partial class Startup
{
    // Anwendung für die Verwendung von "OAuthAuthorization" aktivieren. Anschließend können Sie Ihre Web-APIs sichern.
    static Startup()
    {
        PublicClientId = "web";

        OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/Account/Authorize"),
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60),
            AllowInsecureHttp = true
        };
    }

    public static OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthOptions { get; private set; }

    public static string PublicClientId { get; private set; }

    // Weitere Informationen zum Konfigurieren der Authentifizierung finden Sie unter "http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864".
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Konfigurieren des db-Kontexts, des Benutzer-Managers und des Anmelde-Managers für die Verwendung einer einzelnen Instanz pro Anforderung.
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

        // Anwendung für die Verwendung eines Cookies zum Speichern von Informationen für den angemeldeten Benutzer aktivieren
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
            LogoutPath = new PathString("/Account/LogOff"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                // Aktiviert die Anwendung für die Überprüfung des Sicherheitsstempels, wenn sich der Benutzer anmeldet.
                // Dies ist eine Sicherheitsfunktion, die verwendet wird, wenn Sie ein Kennwort ändern oder Ihrem Konto eine externe Anmeldung hinzufügen.  
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator
            .OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser, Guid>(
                validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60),
                regenerateIdentityCallback: (manager, user) =>
                    user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager),
                getUserIdCallback: (id) => new Guid((id.GetUserId())))
            }
        });
        // Ein Cookie zum vorübergehenden Speichern von Informationen zu einem Benutzer verwenden, der sich mit dem Anmeldeanbieter eines Drittanbieters anmeldet
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        // Aktiviert die Anwendung für das vorübergehende Speichern von Benutzerinformationen beim Überprüfen der zweiten Stufe im zweistufigen Authentifizierungsvorgang.
        app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60));

        // Aktiviert die Anwendung für das Speichern der zweiten Anmeldeüberprüfungsstufe (z. B. Telefon oder E-Mail).
        // Wenn Sie diese Option aktivieren, wird Ihr zweiter Überprüfungsschritt während des Anmeldevorgangs auf dem Gerät gespeichert, von dem aus Sie sich angemeldet haben.
        // Dies ähnelt der RememberMe-Option bei der Anmeldung.
        app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);

        // Anwendung für die Verwendung eines Trägertokens zum Authentifizieren von Benutzern aktivieren
        app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);

        // Auskommentierung der folgenden Zeilen aufheben, um die Anmeldung mit Anmeldeanbietern von Drittanbietern zu ermöglichen
        //app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(
        //    clientId: "",
        //    clientSecret: "");

        //app.UseTwitterAuthentication(
        //    consumerKey: "",
        //    consumerSecret: "");

        //app.UseFacebookAuthentication(
        //    appId: "",
        //    appSecret: "");

        //app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
        //{
        //    ClientId = "",
        //    ClientSecret = ""
        //});
    }
}
```

Comment: When 403 error shows up? Please include error message details and any actions you have made when the error strikes again.

Comment: Do you have a sub code?

Comment: Could it be caused by a Session Timeout or expiring cookies, combined with somehow the redirect to the Login page not working properly?

Comment: Right out of nothing. Yesterday I published the Project. Now this morning it doesn't work anymore. It's a 403-Acces Denied Error from the IIS. 

I tried diffrent App Pools, SSL and No SSl. Restarting the Server, Restarting the IIS.

Comment: without a [mcve] that reproduces the problem the best we can do is guess.

Comment: @PeterB I am trying  to check this!

Comment: @Nkosi  It's not possible to reproduce. It works and at some point it just doesn't anymore. On My Local IIS Express i never had this problem.

Comment: @Markus_DE_HH, Show Auth configuration. could be something in the setup.

Comment: @Nkosi I have updated my Question

Comment: @PeterB I did a 3 min ExpireTime and I was redrirect just fine to my login page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a mistake in Assemblyinfo which caused the crash.

```
//Correct 
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]

//Caused the Crash
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("de-DE")]
```

Comment: You could at least try and help others with this problem by explaining what the mistake was. This answer is worth less than nothing, except to your accept rating, without any info.

Comment: Edited my Answer